# How can I get Test case execution history by test plan or Tag

Tags: azure-devops, execution, test-plan

I wish to get it automatically and on a higher level sutch as Tag or test plan

I know I can get the outcome history manually from the test case execution history

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge, there is no directly automatic way to get the test case outcome in the test plans page.

But here some ideas for your reference:
1.You could try to use the OData API which will return either a day's or a month's test results to find the test results. It looks like something like this:
[https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/testResults/](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7BOrganizationName%7D/%7BProjectName%7D/_odata/v3.0-preview/testResults/)
2.I search and find some third-party extension in [Azure DevOps extension market](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops?utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=L1BrowseMarketplace&targetId=0efb4611-d565-4cd1-9a64-7d6cb6d7d5f0) such as View Latest Test Result (A custom VSTS extension that displays the latest test results for a test case on the work item form.) or Test-Analysis(Summery
Add to your Azure DevOps new ways to explore your test work, and improve your work analysis. help you to get the right perspective of each Tes Plan).

If this couldn't meet your requirement, we recommend that you can directly report the feature requests:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=suggestion. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate engineering team and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Antonia, Thanks.
Can you please share a working link for the OData API?

Comment: Maybe you could see the explanation [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/can-i-get-test-cases-outcome-results-as-a-field-in/359308#T-N599667)